# MySQL - join one to many via pivot table and group results in one row

Tags: mysql

I have following tables structure:

```
jobs
    -id
    -name

jobs_type
    -id
    -name

job_job_type
    jobs_id
    jobs_type_id
```

One **job** can have **many job types**. How can I select all job types for the job and show in one row. I want to have a result similar to this:

```
jobID, jobName, jobTypes
```

Comment: use 2 `JOIN`s in the query `jobs` -> `jobs_jobs_type` -> `jobs_type`

Comment: Hint: Search for GROUP_CONCAT and JSON_ARRAYAGG. But why do you need it in one row?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I need it to write a bit bigger query which have a lot more moving parts and I need to format this data in the frontend (in JS), and show all jobs from the query. If I don't put it in one row, I will get multiple same jobs, and if I group jobs, I won't get all job types. So I need job types as one result per one job

Comment: Then you shouldn't write "for **the** job". This sounds like you need data for a specific single job only.

Comment: Would be easier for you to transform your datas in the backend

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have job types for every job, this (untested) query might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  jobs.id as jobID,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  jobs.name as jobName,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  GROUP_CONCAT(jobs_type.name) as jobTypes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
FROM jobs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
JOIN job_job_type on jobs.id=job_job_type.jobs_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
JOIN jobs_type on job_job_type.jobs_type_id=jobs_type.id                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
GROUP BY 1,2
```

If you aren't guaranteed to have job types for every job, use left joins instead. See the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for GROUP_CONCAT for details on options such as the separator, ordering, and length limitations.